# Find Label in Selenium Python

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Selenium PhantomJS to perform headless dynamic scraping. I was able to extract all information except popups triggered by an `ng-click`, such as:

```
 <button href="#" ng-click="navigation.login({edu:false})">login</button>
 <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()">signup</a>
```

I want to get the tag that contains ng-click label, so that I can perform onclick activity and extract information from it.

The `ng-click` value and tag can be anything, I just want to search whether a tag contains `ng-click` or not, and if it is then return that tag.
I don't want to use regex or something like that.

Comment: Why not use a regex?

Comment: not a good option...

Comment: XPATH is how you solve these problems easily though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works.

`elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[(@ng-click)]")`

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is using XPath to check length of value of ng-click.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[string-length(@ng-click) > 1]")
for element in elements:
    element.click()
```